# Extract concatenates variables from a string by a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am currently working on a data mining project. I have to read a C# source code and I have to get places where an SQL statement gets concatenated. What I really want is to get the name of the concatenated string variable names.

Example:

```
stat = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER c WHERE c.name ='" + name + "' AND c.address = " + address;
```

What I want to extract is

name, address

This I achieved with the following regular expression:

```
(?<=[\+])\s*(?<=[^\"])(\.|_|[a-zA-Z]|\(\))+(?<=[^\"])\s*(?=\s*\+*)
```

But a problem arises in the following situation.

```
stat = name + "' AND c.address = " + address;
```

The following statement does not take a name variable. The problem is to get all the variables from the statement.

Comment: Is there some reason you're required to use a regular expression?  I don't think that's an appropriate tool for this job.  You need a parser.

Comment: I use regular expression to reduce complexity coding and also I have been going through SQL parsers and they reduce the efficiency of the program when scanning huge code base.

Comment: If your SQL statements can have pluses inside of them, then you should consider using a parser to solve this problem.

Comment: If you suggest a SQL parser for this problem, it could be chaos. Because when data mining we could not expect complete SQL statements. we got stat = stat + "WHERE t.name" + name; like half statments. So a lot of SQL parsers fail when input an invalid SQL statement.

Comment: Regular expressions are good for certain kinds of jobs.  But when you try to use them for tasks they're not good for, you increase complexity, not reduce it.  And really long regexes with lots of special operators, such as the one you posted (which doesn't work in all cases), already make things more complex.  Finally, I think you need a C# parser, not an SQL parser, because you don't actually care what's in the string literals, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not a pancea which can cure all woes, and in this case, I believe that you will get better mileage simply splitting the line of code containing the query string:

```
String line = "stat = \"SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER c WHERE c.name ='\" + name + \"' AND c.address = \" + address;";

// spilt on the + symbol, and remove the ending semicolon
String[] parts = line.substring(0, line.length()-1).split("\\+");

for (String part : parts) {
    // variables will not be contained in quotation marks
    if (!part.contains("\"")) {
        System.out.println(part.trim());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
name
address
```

Note that you may need to add additional logic to determine whether a given line of code even contains a SQL query.  In this case, you could try something like `line.contains("SELECT")`, which would match all `SELECT` statements.  This could be expanded to match all sorts of SQL expressions you expect to see in the code.

Comment: This will fail-in in PL-SQL sql line that contain + inside the string "+".

Comment: @IsuruMadusanka Good call.  It won't fail for something like `SELECT a + b` but it does fail for `SELECT a + b + c`.  Not sure if there is an easy way around this.